# How to deploy Pentaho Kettle transformation as restful web-service

Tags: web-services, restful-url, kettle

I was wondering if it's possible to deploy Kettle ETL jobs as RESTful web-services in a standard way, i.e. Java EE-Container like Tomcat / Jetty / JBoss.

What I'm looking for in detail is:

- some way to bind URL parameters to the ETL process, preferably within the Kettle IDE.

  So, as an example

  `http://myservice/customers/201301122`

  would get all new customers as of 20130122.

A huge plus would be:

- the ability to start and test services within the IDE.
- the ability to export a service in a single self contained WAR-Archive

Answer (score 0):

give a peek to [carte server](http://wiki.pentaho.com/display/eai/the+thin+kettle+jdbc+driver)
it's not exactly REST but...

Comment: Correct; However some work has just been done to make Carte restful: http://michaeldamour.blogspot.co.uk/

Comment: Just watching the PDI 5.0 webex - turns out that the restful stuff will be in that version.  Can be previewed in CI though!